# Prerender angular universal doesn't work in Firebase

Tags: angular, firebase, server-side-rendering, angular-universal, prerender

Hi guys I have a problem with my angual universal app.
I can safely deploy my app to firebase, but the prerender doesn't work since the metatags of the various routes don't change.

using the "ng deploy" command from the angular cli, the app is properly built and prerendered and then deployed to firebase.

I have the free firebase account and I read that for prerendering there are no problems.

can anyone help me?

I have this in my angular.json:

```
"prerender": {
      "builder": "@nguniversal/builders:prerender",
      "options": {
        "routes": [
          "manyRoutes"
        ]
      },
      "configurations": {
        "production": {
          "browserTarget": "app:build:production",             
          "serverTarget": "app:server:production"
        },
        "development": {
          "browserTarget": "app:build:development",
          "serverTarget": "app:server:development"
        }
      },
      "defaultConfiguration": "production"
    },
"deploy": {
      "builder": "@angular/fire:deploy",
      "options": {
        "prerender": true,
        "ssr": false,
        "browserTarget": "app:build:production",
        "firebaseProject": "app",
        "firebaseHostingSite": "app",            
        "prerenderTarget": "app:prerender:production"              
      }
    }
```

firebase.json:

```
{"hosting": [
    {
      "public": "dist/app/browser",
      "ignore": [
        "firebase.json",
        "**/.*",
        "**/node_modules/**"
      ],
      "rewrites": [
        {
          "source": "**",
          "destination": "/index.html"          
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "target": "app",
      "public": "dist/app/browser",
      "ignore": [
        "**/.*"
      ],
      "headers": [
        {
          "source": "*.[0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f][0-9a-f].+(css|js)",
          "headers": [
            {
              "key": "Cache-Control",
              "value": "public,max-age=31536000,immutable"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "source": "/@(ngsw-worker.js|ngsw.json)",
          "headers": [
            {
              "key": "Cache-Control",
              "value": "no-cache"
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "rewrites": [
        {
          "source": "**",
          "destination": "/index.html"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

it's probably a configuration problem. i hope someone can point out my mistakes.

Comment: Hosting config? I.e. `firebase.json`

Comment: I added the firebase.json